# Can I create a universal function for scraping event lists?

Tags: html, ruby, events, web-scraping, calendar

I am working on a project where I want to display a large list of events, but in order to do so, I have to pull event data from multiple sites. Some of them have calendars, some have plain HTML lists; basically, every site offers the data differently.

Would I have to scrape each site individually, or is there a universal function that I could create that would save data from each website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) to scrape the data from your sources. You will need to specify the HTML tags from where you want to pull the information, Nokogiri will parse the HTML and give selectors that allow you to move around the parsed DOM.

You can use something like [Portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) if you want to scrape the data but you need to evaluate if it's the right tool based on the websites you want to scrape.

Comment: So basically I'd have to customize the query per each site, since their element structure is bound to be inherently different? I feel like there has to be a better way to do this, but have absolutely no idea what that involves.